# Handling several Realm Files

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am new to Realm.io and have the following question :

Working with several realm-files and accessing them in the same thread consecutively. Do all of these .realm-files have to have the same RLMObjects ?

```
 NSString *Path_1 = @"....path1/realmfile_1.realm";
 NSString *Path_2 = @"....path2/realmfile_2.realm";

 RLMRealm *realm_1 = [RLMRealm realmWithPath:Path_1];
 RLMObject_1 *Object_1_ToAdd = [[RLMObject_1 alloc] init];
 [realm_1 beginWriteTransaction];
 Object_1_ToAdd.property_xy = @"bla1";
 [realm_1 commitWriteTransaction];

 RLMRealm *realm_2 = [RLMRealm realmWithPath:Path_2];
 RLMObject_2 *Object_2_ToAdd = [[RLMObject_2 alloc] init];
 [realm_2 beginWriteTransaction];
 Object_2_ToAdd.property_ab = @"bla2";
 [realm_2 commitWriteTransaction];
```

Do both .realm-files (i.e. realmfile_1.realm and realmfile_2.realm) need both RLMObjects (i.e. RLMObject_1 and RLMObject_2) ?

Is it correct that the migration-block call (see below) creates all RLMObjects in all realmfiles and if yes - why ?????

So far, all RLMObjects in my code are placed in all .realm-files - why ??? Or is this the way realm works ??

Thanks on any help on this !

SetSchemaVersion :

```
[RLMRealm setSchemaVersion:1 withMigrationBlock:^(RLMMigration *migration, NSUInteger oldSchemaVersion) { }
```

The following image shows the realm-browser screenshot (see below) of one realm-file (the other looks the same !). Is there a way that one file consinsts of RLMObject_1 and another file consists of RLMObject_2 ?? How would I have to set up the RLMObject definition classes ??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Realm will consider every RLMObject subclass to be part of your data model. This is done to greatly simplify development since developers only have to declare their model once.

Empty tables take very little space in Realm files and are inexpensive to create, which is why Realm works this way.

If you're determined to only create relevant tables for each realm, you could construct your own `RLMSchema`, but we won't be able to officially support you in that case since that's not part of the public API.

Comment: Thank you jpsim ! That makes sense now !

Comment: @jpsim - can you confirm that because every table is in every file, if I change the class structure (schema) of a class - for which there is no data in a file, that file still needs to go through a migration